# How many numbers are there of 5 figures..

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers can be considered of five figures (from 10000 to 99999) if we require that exactly
four different figures appear in nondecreasing order (example: 23779)?

The solution is 4*C(9,4). I understand the *4 since we are gonna choose the number which will be equal to one of the other 4, but why C(9,4)?

Comment: There are **$9$ choose $4$** ways to choose the four distinct digits that appear, and $4$ ways to choose which digit appears twice.

Comment: But in that case we will get every possible combination of the 4 numbers, even those which are decreasing, right?

Comment: For each choice of the digits, there is exactly one non-decreasing arrangement of them.

Answer (score 1):

Let the five digit number is $$X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5$$ where condition is that of five digits 4 are distinct and there exist inequality $X_1\le X_2 \le X_3 \le X_4 \le X_5$
$$ $$
Consider along with nine digits 1,2,4,....,9 assume four more distinct objects $X_{(1,2)},X_{(2,3)},X_{(3,4)},X_{(4,5)}$ where $X_{(i,i+1)}$ indicate digit $X_i \,and \,X_{i+1}$ are equal.
$$ $$
Number of ways are from 9 digit select any 4 and from different $X_{(i,i+1)}$ select 1 we get required number 
$$={9 \choose 4}{4 \choose 1}$$
$$=504$$